# Saida de uma Rede Neural Recorrente com o Tensorflow e Keras

Tags: python, redes-neurais, tensorflow, keras

Eu montei um dataset com meus dados de imagens. Eu quero fazer o treinamento de uma rede neural convolucional mas acabei parando na camada de saida da rede. A ideia depois de treinar a rede é gerar uma imagem a partir dessa rede treinada (problema de regressão). Porém, na hora de treinar a rede eu encontrei a seguinte msg de erro:

ValueError: A target array with shape (1501, 32, 32, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Como posso corrigir isso?

Abaixo segue o meu código:

```
import os
import PIL
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import cv2
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
files = glob.glob ("E:/NN_SRTM/Teste_Split_imagem/srtm_treino/*.tif")

y = []
files1 = glob.glob ("E:/NN_SRTM/Teste_Split_imagem/gnsstreino/*.tif")

IMG_SIZE = 32

for myFile in files:
    print(myFile)
    image = cv2.imread (myFile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    x.append (image)

for myFile1 in files1:
    print(myFile1)
    image1 = cv2.imread (myFile1, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image1 = cv2.resize(image1, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    y.append (image1)

x = np.array(x)
x = x.astype('float32')

y = np.array(y)
y = y.astype('float32')

x = x.reshape(x.shape[0],32,32,1)
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0],32,32,1)

X_treinamento, X_teste, y_treinamento, y_teste = train_test_split(x,y, 
                                                                  test_size=0.30,random_state=0)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding="same", 
                                 activation="relu", input_shape=[32, 32, 1]))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, 
                                 padding="same", activation="relu"))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding="same", activation="relu"))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2, padding='valid'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer="Adam", 
              metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()

model.fit(X_treinamento, y_treinamento, epochs=5)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Grato pela atenção

Comment: Para gerar novas imagens você deve pesquisar sobre **Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs)** [aqui tem uns exemplos](https://pathmind.com/wiki/generative-adversarial-network-gan)

Comment: Eu acreditava q uma CNN poderia gerar isso mais rápido. Mas entendi a sua colocação. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O problema de gerar imagens artificiais não é um problema de regressão. É conhecido na literatura como [modelos generativos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_model), dentre eles temos as Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) que é uma classe de modelos generativos, dentre dessa classe foram desenvolvidos diversos trabalhos com ótimos resultados na geração de imagens artificiais, segue uma [demonstração](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QuDh3W3lOY).